# Android development

Tags: android, android-emulator

The applications has stopped unexpectedly

I get this error when pressing a button on a specified page.

This code hangs the application:
--Code snippet

```
    <Button android:text="Button" 
    android:onClick="SaveRegistration" 
    android:id="@+id/btnAddRegistration" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>       

public void SaveRegistration(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I run on version 2.2

Logcat errorlog

```
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method add(View) in the activity class com.millerbean.gasApp.MillerbeansGasInfoActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnTest'
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: add
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2124)
06-26 14:25:52.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447):     ... 11 more
06-26 14:25:52.643: WARN/ActivityManager(75):   Force finishing activity com.millerbean.gasApp/.MillerbeansGasInfoActivity
06-26 14:25:53.193: WARN/ActivityManager(75): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4050f5b0 com.millerbean.gasApp/.MillerbeansGasInfoActivity}
```

Problem solved!

In my main java file I have the following on my first button:
setContentView(R.layout.newregistration);
it change the layout to another xml file newregistration.xml

Later on I created a Addregistration.java file where I placed the event handler.
The event handler needed to be placed in my main java file and now it works.

What is the difference between:
1. setContentView(R.layout.newregistration);
2. startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuBuilder.class));

Is it correct that 1. set the layouts that the user see 2. set which class to get eventhandlers and etc.

Comment: can you post Detailed Error Message by Seeing LogCat

Comment: Im a totally beginner... Can you explain how to post this ?

Comment: What SDK level are you building against it's todo with your onClick declared in your XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you remove

```
android:onClick="SaveRegistration"
```

from your layout and do it in your code, e.g.

```
Button myButton = this.findViewById(btnAddRegistration);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                SaveRegistration(v);
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your class extend `Activity` like below?

From Android site:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

Edit: Does commenting out the Toast cause the error to go away? If so, this is likely the problem. Work your way through the [Android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Comment: Yes it extends the Activity and outcommenting the Toast does not help.